# Can I specify a minimum CPU power for one thread

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, express, cpu

I've just started to use the npm threads package to move parts of my node server code into separate threads.

What I'm curious about is if I can specify that a certain thread gets a minimum share of the CPU that other threads aren't allowed to steal from.

My worry is that if my main loop spawns separate threads of intensive algorithms in order to prevent the intensive code from blocking other server operations, will the other thread end up hogging so much CPU that the main loop still significantly slows down anyway?

I'd want to set a minimum CPU for the main loop so that it can still do its stuff lag free regardless of the other threads i've spawned.

Comment: you can use `Pool` to create a thread pool that spawns a fixed number of workers;  if you create more threads than workers, the extras get queued.

Comment: most computers can hyperthread and have more than one CPU

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is thread priority, which can indeed be influenced from nodejs (on linux) https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/1253